# Adding confidence interval to bootstrap abline to graph in R

Tags: r, graph, confidence-interval

I am not sure how to elegantly add some boot strap confidence intervals obtained from bootstrap to my graph, using R.

Hello. I am trying to add confidence intervals to my graph in R.

I had little data, so I used bootstrap. My initial code looks like this:

```
data.df <- read.csv("E:\\data\\data.csv")
library(boot)

matplot(data.df[, 1], data.df[, -1], type="l",
    main="Data",xlab="Year", ylab=" ", yaxt="n",
    xlim=c(1970, 2015), ylim=c(15, 95), 
    lwd=c(1, 4, 4, 4),  
    col=c("black", "red", "burlywood", "cadetblue"), 
    lty=c("solid", "dotted", "dotted", "dotted" ))
    lmodel6=lm(data.df$avg~data.df$X)
    abline(lmodel6$coefficients[1],lmodel6$coefficients[2],col=1,lwd=4)
```

I used matplot rather than just regular plot. In the past I have been used to using matplot, so I figured to continue using those.

Next, I did bootstrap:

```
results <- boot(data=data.df, statistic=bs, R=1000, formula=avg~X)
results

bs <- function(formula, data, indices) {
    d <- data[indices,]
    fit <- lm(formula, data=d)
    return(coef(fit))
}

boot.ci(results, type="bca", index=1)
boot.ci(results, type="bca", index=2)
```

I am hoping to get some result that looks like:

[image]

But, most examples of adding confidence intervals to plots online use regular plot or ggplot. Or, they do not deal with bootstrap. Other places such as: https://thomasleeper.com/Rcourse/Tutorials/olsresultplots.html , produce some nice graphs but they use a different procedure and different code.

Any guidance or assistance would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm puzzled. Is it true that supplying a formula to `boot` will automagically result in a regression being done? I don't see that documented in the `boot::boot` help page.

Comment: I don't know why I forgot to include some code - this BS thing should be in there, and it's added now, as the initial post has been edited.